# .NET Generic Method Question

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to grasp the concept of .NET Generics and actually use them in my own code but I keep running into a problem.

Can someone try to explain to me why the following setup does not compile?

```
public class ClassA
{
    ClassB b = new ClassB();

    public void MethodA<T>(IRepo<T> repo) where T : ITypeEntity
    {
        b.MethodB(repo);
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    IRepo<ITypeEntity> repo;

    public void MethodB(IRepo<ITypeEntity> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
cannot convert from IRepo<'T> to IRepo<'ITypeEntity>

MethodA gets called with a IRepo<'DetailType> object parameter where DetailType inherits from ITypeEntity.

I keep thinking that this should compile as I'm constraining T within MethodA to be of type ITypeEntity.

Any thoughts or feedback would be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Nick R has a great suggestion but unfortunately in my context, I don't have the option of making ClassA Generic.  ClassB could be though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance doesn't work the same when using generics. As Smashery points out, even if TypeA inherits from TypeB, myType<TypeA> doesn't inherit from myType<TypeB>.

As such, you can't make a call to a method defined as MethodA(myType<TypeB> b) expecting a myType<TypeB> and give it a myType<TypeA> instead. The types in question have to match exactly. Thus, the following won't compile:

```
myType<TypeA> a; // This should be a myType<TypeB>, even if it contains only TypeA's

public void MethodB(myType<TypeB> b){ /* do stuff */ }

public void Main()
{
  MethodB(a);
}
```

So in your case, you would need to pass in an IRepo<ITypeEntity> to MethodB, even if it only contains DetailTypes. You'd need to do some conversion between the two. If you were using a generic IList, you might do the following:

```
public void MethodA<T>(IList<T> list) where T : ITypeEntity
{
  IList<T> myIList = new List<T>();

  foreach(T item in list)
  {
    myIList.Add(item);
  }

  b.MethodB(myIList);
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Well this compiles ok. I basically redifined the classes to take generic parameters. This may be ok in your context.

```
public interface IRepo<TRepo>
{
}

public interface ITypeEntity
{
}


public class ClassA<T> where T : ITypeEntity
{
    ClassB<T> b = new ClassB<T>();
    public void MethodA(IRepo<T> repo)
    {
        b.MethodB(repo);
    }
}
public class ClassB<T> where T : ITypeEntity
{
    IRepo<T> repo;
    public void MethodB(IRepo<T> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're generic'ing up the first class the 2nd will also need to be generic'ed

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option to make ClassA a Generic class as it is a ASP .Net User Control and I really don't want to try to figure out that problem.  Thanks for your thought though.  It was perfectly reasonable based on the limited context I gave.

Comment: In that case, do you need to use generics?  It strikes me the problem is because ClassA contains an object of type ClassB. Try to implement without generics first - that may be adequate.

Comment: The IRepo interface is Generic.  I cannot change that.  At least I think I can't.  Maybe I'll look into that a little more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a tricky one to get your head around. DetailType may inherit from ITypeEntity, but isn't actually ITypeEntity. Your implementation of DetailType could introduce different functionality, so DetailType implements ITypeEntity but isn't equal to ITypeEntity. I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

> I get the following error: cannot
>   convert from IRepo<'T> to
>   IRepo<'ITypeEntity>

You are getting this compilation error because `IRepo<T>` and `IRepo<ITypeEntity>` are *not* the same thing. The latter is a specialization of the former. `IRepo<T>` is a *generic type definition*, where the type parameter T is a placeholder, and `IRepo<ITypeEntity>` is a *constructured generic type* of the generic type definition, where the type parameter T from is specified to be `ITypeEntity`.

> I keep thinking that this should
>   compile as I'm constraining T within
>   MethodA to be of type ITypeEntity.

The `where` constraint does not help here because it only contrains the type you can provide for T at the call-sites for `MethodA`.

Here is the terminology from the MSDN documentation (see [Generics in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx)) that may help:

- A generic type definition is a
  class, structure, or interface
  declaration that functions as a
  template, with placeholders for the
  types that it can contain or use.
  For example, the `Dictionary<<K, V>` class can contain
  two types: keys and values. Because
  it is only a template, you cannot
  create instances of a class,
  structure, or interface that is a
  generic type definition.
- Generic type parameters, or type
  parameters, are the placeholders in
  a generic type or method definition.
  The `Dictionary<K, V>` generic type has two type
  parameters, K and V, that
  represent the types of its keys and
  values.
- A constructed generic type, or
  constructed type, is the result of
  specifying types for the generic
  type parameters of a generic type
  definition.
- A generic type argument is any type
  that is substituted for a generic
  type parameter.
- The general term generic type
  includes both constructed types and
  generic type definitions.
- Constraints are limits placed on
  generic type parameters. For
  example, you might limit a type
  parameter to types that implement
  the `IComparer<T>` generic
  interface, to ensure that instances
  of the type can be ordered. You can
  also constrain type parameters to
  types that have a particular base
  class, that have a default
  constructor, or that are reference
  types or value types. Users of the
  generic type cannot substitute type
  arguments that do not satisfy the
  constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [@monoxide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110121/logic-and-its-application-to-collectionsgeneric-and-inheritance)'s question

And [as I said there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110121/logic-and-its-application-to-collectionsgeneric-and-inheritance#110137), checking out Eric Lippert's series of posts on contravariance and covariance for generics will make a lot of this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If B is a subclass of A, that does not mean that `Class<B>` is a subclass of `Class<A>`. So, for this same reason, if you say "`T` is an `ITypeEntity`", that does not mean that "`IRepo<T>` is an `IRepo<ITypeEntity>`". You might have to write your own conversion method if you want to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

T is a type variable that will be bound to a partcular type in usage. The restriction ensures that that type will represent a **subset** of the types that implement ITypeEntity, excluding other types that implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

at compile time even though you're constraining it the compiler only knows that T in MethodA is a reference type. it doesn't know what type it is constrained to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a redundant use of generics, if T can only ever be an instance of ITypeEntity you shouldn't use generics.

Generics are for when you have multiple types which can be inside something.

Comment: That is not quite right.  T can be any object that implements ITypeEntity.  This is a correct use of generics.

Comment: Yes, but because ITypeEntity is an interface you can cast the object back to an ITypeEntity at any point. So to actually pass something into that generic argument it has to implement ITypeEntity, in turn it "is" ITypeEntity

Answer (score 0):

In the context of wrapping your head around generic methods, allow me to give you a simple generic function.  It's a generic equivalent of VB's IIf() (Immediate if), which is itself a poor imitation of the C-style ternary operator (?). It's not useful for anything since the real ternary operator is better, but maybe it will help you understand how generic function are built and in what contexts they should be applied.

```
T IIF<T>(bool Expression, T TruePart, T FalsePart)
{
    return Expression ? TruePart : FalsePart;
}
```