# Converting Enumeration to Iterator

Tags: generics, scala, iterator, enumeration, type-inference

I have the following implicit conversion for `java.util.Enumerations`

```
   implicit def enumerationIterator[A](e : Enumeration[A]) : Iterator[A] = {
     new Iterator[A] {
        def hasNext = e.hasMoreElements
        def next = e.nextElement
        def remove = throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
     }
   }
```

Unfortunately it does not work for `ZipFile.entries` because it returns an `Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>` (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618148/difference-between-enumeration-extends-zipentry-and-enumerationzipentry)) and Scalac keeps telling me

```
type mismatch; found : java.util.Iterator[?0] 
   where type ?0 <: java.util.zip.ZipEntry 
   required: Iterator[?]
```

I can't figure out how to make the conversation work in sth. like

```
List.fromIterator(new ZipFile(z).entries))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List.fromIterator expects a scala.Iterator but your implicit is returning a java.util.Iterator.

This works

```
import java.util.Enumeration

implicit def enum2Iterator[A](e : Enumeration[A]) = new Iterator[A] {
  def next = e.nextElement
  def hasNext = e.hasMoreElements
}

import java.util.zip.{ZipFile, ZipEntry}
val l = List.fromIterator(new ZipFile(null:java.io.File).entries)
```

Adding one import at the top prevents compilation

```
import java.util.Iterator
```

There's been some discussion about unifying Scala and Java in 2.8 by just using java.util.Iterator.   On the downside, Java's Iterator has a remove method which makes no sense for Scala's immutable collections.  UnsupportedOperationException? Blech! On the plus side that makes stuff like this error go away.

Edit: I've added a Trac issue that the error message would have been clearer had it said "required: scala.Iterator[?]" https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2102

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Enumeration in Scala 2.7.x has an "elements" method and Scala 2.8.0 has an "iterator" method returing an Iterator. Why not use them?

Oh, never mind, never mind. *Java's* enumeration.