# IList<Type> to IList<BaseType>

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have a few classes:

```
class Vehicle
{
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
}
```

I have a list of the derived class:
    `IList<Car> cars;`

I would like to convert the list to its base class, and have tried:
    `IList<Vehicle> baseList = cars as IList<Vehicle>;`

But I always get `null`. Also

```
cars is IList<Vehicle> evaluates to be false.
```

Granted, I can add the items to a list if I do the following:

```
List<Vehicle> test = new List<Vehicle> ();

foreach ( Car car in cars )
{
   test.Add(car);
}
```

And I get my list, but I know there has to be a better way.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981570/c-no-implict-conversion-from-classchild-to-classbase and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296892/c-interface-implementation-and-generic-collections-question at least.

Comment: Robert Harvey: Of course there is an alternative way; he could create an implementation of IList<BaseType> that is basically a wrapper over an existing IList<Type>. This way, he wouldn't have to cast all of the elements, only the ones that are needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [IEnumerable`<T>`.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) :

```
IList<Vehicle> vehicles = cars.Cast<Vehicle>().ToList();
```

Alternatively, you may be able to avoid the conversion to List depending on how you wish to process the source car list.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: The .Net Framework 3.5 has been released almost two years ago. I think it is safe to assume that everyone has it by now unless they have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Note that this results in a new list, not a reference to the same list.

Answer (score 12):

That sort of polymorphism that lets you cast `IList<Car>` to `IList<Vehicle>` is unsafe, because it would let you insert a `Truck` in your `IList<Car>`.

Comment: He's not trying to cast it, but create a new list instance.

Comment: uh, no. He's trying to assign a (reference to a) list of the base type from a (reference to a) list of the derived type, and wondering why he gets null. If he were trying to make a new instance, this would work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You're facing the problem that there is limited co- and contravariance in C#. There is an interesting approach in C# 4.0, described [here at the very ending](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx). However, it creates some other limitations that are related to the truck-problem in the answer from Novelocrat.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of approaches using Linq:

```
IList<Derived> list = new List<Derived>();
list.Add(new Derived());

IList<Base> otherlist = new List<Base>(from item in list select item as Base);
IList<Base> otherlist2 = new List<Base>(list.Select(item => item as Base));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look on Krzysztof's Cwalina article, [Simulated Covariance for .NET Generics](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2008/04/02/SimulatedCovariance.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var vehicles = cars.OfType<IVehicle>()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `IList` all of the way, then you are out of luck and the answers above can help you. However, if you can use an `IList` that is casted as `IEnumerable` and then simply re-casted at the destination as `IList`, that would work, since `IEnumerable` can accept such practice.

```
// At the source or at the model.
IEnumerable<BaseType> list = new List<Type>();
// At the destination.
IList<BaseType> castedList = (IList<BaseType>)list;
```

Although, since the compiler cannot enforce these things, you must manually make sure that the types and base types indeed match, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `IReadOnlyList<T>` from .NET 4.5+ will allow you to cast `IReadOnlyList<Car>` into `IReadOnlyList<Vehicle>` with no problems.  `List<T>` and `Collection<T>` implement this interface.