# Why can't you cast from IList<IParent> to IList<IChild> where IChild implements IParent

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, list, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IList<Type> to IList<BaseType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457265/ilisttype-to-ilistbasetype)

I am programming in C# using .NET 2.0 and I don't understand why the cast below results in a null reference.

If you have an IList<IChild>, why can't you cast it to an IList<IParent> where IChild implements IParent.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace InterfaceTest
{
    public interface IParent
    {
    }

    public interface IChild : IParent
    {
    }

    public abstract class Parent : IParent
    {
    }

    public sealed class Child : Parent, IChild
    {
    }

    public sealed class Container
    {
        public IList<IChild> ChildInterfaceList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Container()
        {
            ChildInterfaceList = new List<IChild>();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Container container = new Container();

            var childInterfaceList = container.ChildInterfaceList;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(childInterfaceList != null);

            var parentInterfaceList = container.ChildInterfaceList as IList<IParent>;

            //I don't expect parentInterfaceList to be null, but it is
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(parentInterfaceList != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457265 .  Also possibly useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx

Answer (score 3):

C# mutable collections do not support variance on the collection element type.  Consider what would happen if you did this:

```
IList<IChild> kids = new List<IChild> {
    new Egg("Shelly"), new Egg("Egbert"), new Egg("Yoko")
};

var parents = kids as IList<IParent>;

parents.Add(new Sloth("Sid")); // what would happen here?
```

If the cast succeeded, the run-time type of `parents` would still be `List<IChild>` which would not accept something that does not implement `IChild`, and would have to throw an exception.

An acceptable conversion would be:

```
using System.Linq;
var parents = kids.Cast<IParent>().ToList();
```

which would create a *copy* of the original list, but with `List<IParent>` as its run-time type.

Generic variance is supported in C# 4.0, but mutable collections cannot safely be made variant.  Only pure read-only interfaces like `IEnumerable` can safely be made covariant, and pure write-only interfaces (are there any?) can safely be made contravariant.

Comment: Yes there are. IComparer<T> for example is effectively a write-only interface for the purposes of variance. T's go in, results come out, but T's never come out.  A comparer that can compare any two animals can also compare any two giraffes, so IComparer<Animal> can be converted to IComparer<Giraffe> contravariantly.

Comment: An object of type IEnumerable is not guaranteed to be readonly.

IEnumerable<T> someList = new List<T>(); //someList very much writable :)

Comment: Right, but irrelevant. There's no way to get at the mutating methods via IEnumerable, which is what is relevant. That fact allows us to safely make IE<T> covariant in T.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I guess I got my directions of variance mixed up -- contravariance inverts the narrower-than relationship between types, making IComparer<Animal> onto IComparer<Giraffe> a widening conversion. I think the use of a cast attempting to widen the *type parameter* in the question mixed me up.  Serves me right for posting while feeling ill. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pitfall.

Consider this simple explanation-by-example:

Everything in .NET inherits from `Object`, right? So, let's suppose what you wanted were possible...

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
List<object> objects = ints as List<object>;
objects.Add("Hello there!");
```

You've just tried to add a `string` to what is actually a list of integers.